# Why autocomplete="off" is not working in HTML?

Tags: html, autocomplete

Hi i need to disable autocomplete in login page, I have this line in my html

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" />
```

But autocomplete still present.

I'm using Firefox and chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers intentionally ignore `autocomplete="off"`. Sites disable that for no good reason, and in the end, browsers decided to call it a day and kick that feature off the list. It's like `<blink>` in that way.

NB: Turning it off because 'the boss told me so' or 'some misguided security guide' told me so. i.e. most likely the very thing you are trying to accomplish is exactly what browsers did not want to happen. The purpose of this feature has always been to take username-like fields that aren't actually login fields, and tell the browser. Instead the `autocomplete` feature is used to try to disagree with the browser on proper security protocols.

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion) for more info.

Chrome 38, firefox 34, and even IE11 all agree: Disabling autocomplete for security purposes is bad, and therefore, they just ignore your directive. Has nothing to do with JSP.

Comment: What should be used instead - say, if the site implements its own drop-down autocomplete (as in type-ahead) which competes on the UI with the browser's autofill?

Comment: Maybe javascript. Your question is analogous to 'I have an actual need to blink text, but the `<blink>` tag no longer works, now what?'. The answer is: Oookay, that's annoying for you, and makes it complicated. If it was easy to forcibly get that no-autocomplete stuff going, boneheaded implementers of backwards security principles would then start using it. My apologies for bearing bad news :/

Answer (score 0):

Try This One:

```html
<input type="text" autocomplete="__away">

OR

<input type ="text" autocomplete="false">
```